# Type error while using enum as Select option

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I implemented a custom Select component like this:

```
export const Select = <Value,>({
                                   value,
                                   onChange,
                                   options,
                                   mapOptionToLabel,
                                   mapOptionToValue,
    placeholder
                               }: T_SelectProps<Value>) => {
    const toLabel = (option: Value): T_Allowed => {
        if (mapOptionToLabel) {
            return mapOptionToLabel(option);
        }
        return typeof option === "string" || typeof option === "number" ? option : String(option);
    };

    const toValue = (option: Value): T_Allowed => {
        if (mapOptionToValue) {
            return mapOptionToValue(option);
        }
        return typeof option === "string" || typeof option === "number" ? option : String(option);
    };

    const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
        onChange(options[e.target.selectedIndex]);
    };

    return (
        <select value={toValue(value)} onChange={handleChange} placeholder={placeholder}>
            {options.map((value) => (
                <option value={toValue(value)} key={toValue(value)}>
                    {toLabel(value)}
                </option>
            ))}
        </select>
    );
};
```

Here is defined types for this component:

```
export type T_CreateQuizFormProps = {
    values: T_FormValues;
    onChange: (fieldName: keyof T_FormValues, value: T_FormValues[keyof T_FormValues]) => void;
}

export type T_FormValues = {
    category: number;
    difficulty: Difficulty;
}
```

Where Difficulty is enum:

```
export enum Difficulty {
    EASY = "easy",
    MEDIUM = "medium",
   HARD = "hard"
}
```

Also I have a mapper like:

```
export const difficultyValueToLabelMapper: {[key in Difficulty]: string} = {
    [Difficulty.EASY]: "Easy",
    [Difficulty.HARD]: "Hard",
    [Difficulty.MEDIUM]: "Medium"
}
```

And I am using Select for Difficulty options as:

```
            <Select
                placeholder="Select a difficulty"
                value={values.difficulty}
                onChange={(value: Difficulty) => onChange("difficulty", value)}
                options={Object.values(Difficulty)}
                mapOptionToLabel={mapDifficultyOptionToLabel} />
```

But I've got TS error for options prop for some not obvious reason:

```
TS2322: Type 'Difficulty[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly Difficulty.EASY[] | readonly Difficulty.MEDIUM[] | readonly Difficulty.HARD[]'.
```

I need a help to figure out how to fix this error.

Tried to replace enum with union but I definitely want to use union here.